# Concatenate PHP function output to a string like variables

Tags: php, string, string-concatenation

For variable `$x` we can concatenate it to a string in many ways, one of them is like the following:

```
$x = "Hello";
echo "I say {$x} to all of you.";
// The output should be: I say Hello to all of you.
```

However, If I tried to do something like this with a function, it will fail:

```
$x = "Hello";
echo "I say {strtolower($x)} to all of you.";
// The output should be: I say {strtolower(Hello)} to all of you.
```

If there is a synonym way just like used for the variable, I will be appreciated to know it. In other words, I don't want to split the main string and I don't want to use `sprinf`.

Comment: How about: `echo "I say " . strtolower($x) . " to all of you.";`

Comment: `$x = strtolower("Hello");`

Comment: No, I don't want this way, I like to keep it simple one string just like the variable way.

Comment: I think you look for something like @Fred-ii- posted. You can assign `x` before the echo statement and then use `x` as you used it in the first code box

Comment: Or try a nowdoc http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can concatenate with `.` operator:

```
echo "I say  " . strtolower($x) . " to all of you.";
```

Or just :

```
echo "I say  ", strtolower($x), " to all of you.";
```