# execute php echo as parameter value

Tags: php

I have below code & I am generating tracking_id values manually & its working fine :

```
<?php

$data = [
"client_reference_id" => "ABCD",
"tracking_id" => "1234",
];
$data = json_encode($data);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $curl_response ."\n";
```

Result :

**{"response":[{"tracking_id":"1234",}],**

Now i need to create tracking_id dynamically.... so i tried like below :

```
"tracking_id" => "$r = 'DOCC'. mt_rand(0000000001,9999999999); echo $r;",
```

I got below Result :

**{"response":[{"tracking_id":" = 'DOCC'. mt_rand(0000000001,9999999999); echo ;","**

But i should get some **random number** as tracking_id....

Means php code inside parameter is not working....

Comment: Are you just looking to set a specific key in an array? Don't enclose it all in quotes then: `"tracking_id" => 'DOCC' . mt_rand(0000000001,9999999999),`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate PHP function output to a string like variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494038/concatenate-php-function-output-to-a-string-like-variables)

Comment: @h2ooooooo sometimes it work, but sometime it give this message : `{"response":[{"tracking_id":"DOCC815327051","status":"REQUEST_REJECTED","message":["trackingId : Invalid tracking ID, Provided value: [DOCC815327051]"]}],`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your require 10 digit random number:

```
function randomNumber($length) {
$result = '';

for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $result .= mt_rand(1, 9);
}

return $result;
}

$data = [
"client_reference_id" => "ABCD",
"tracking_id" => 'DOCC'.randomNumber(10);//no need to echo, just assign it
];
$data = json_encode($data);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $curl_response ."\n";
```

Comment: Do reduce the max value mt_rand to mt_rand(1111111,9999999)

Comment: sometimes it work, but sometime it give this message : `{"response":[{"tracking_id":"DOCC815327051","status":"REQUEST_REJECTED","message":["trackingId : Invalid tracking ID, Provided value: [DOCC815327051]"]}],`

Comment: check your api, it might only allow digits. replace with "tracking_id" => mt_rand(1111111,9999999);

Comment: no, it should be in this format only : `DOCC-ten digits`

Comment: do this: "tracking_id" => 'DOCC'.mt_rand(11111,99999).mt_rand(11111,99999);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183126/discussion-between-manpreet-and-vickey-colors).

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your code:

```
$r = 'DOCC'. mt_rand(0000000001,9999999999);

$data = [
  "client_reference_id" => "ABCD",
  "tracking_id" => $r,
];
```

Comment: Thanks, sometimes it work, but sometime it give this message : `{"response":[{"tracking_id":"DOCC815327051","status":"REQUEST_REJECTED","message":["trackingId : Invalid tracking ID, Provided value: [DOCC815327051]"]}],`

Comment: Finally This worked for me : 'DOCC'.mt_rand(11111,99999).mt_rand(11111,99999),

Comment: can you please tell me how to save that tracking number in database ?

Comment: It is best to ask a new question, but here's an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655706/pdo-with-insert-into-through-prepared-statements

Answer (score 0):

Just replace $data array with the following.

```
$data = [
"client_reference_id" => "ABCD",
"tracking_id" => 'DOCC'.  mt_rand(0000000001,9999999999),
];
```

Comment: Thanks , sometimes it work, but sometime it give this message : `{"response":[{"tracking_id":"DOCC815327051","status":"REQUEST_REJECTED","message":["trackingId : Invalid tracking ID, Provided value: [DOCC815327051]"]}],`

Comment: please check the range of trackingId. and change the mt_rand function range

Comment: it should be in this format only : `DOCC-ten digits`

Comment: Finally This worked for me : 'DOCC'.mt_rand(11111,99999).mt_rand(11111,99999),

Comment: can you please tell me how to save that tracking number in database ?

Comment: Which dB are u using?

Comment: Sorry for delay, i am using mysql..... i want to save `tracking_id` in database.....

Comment: connect the db with PDO or mysqli_connect
then run simple INSERT query this will work