# saving a picture with a date

Tags: php, image, date, save

Good day,
I would like to take screenshots from a ESP32 cam and save it on my NAS. I put the following script on my nas, the picture is saved but the name of the picture is:

1. always the same which means that the next picture will overwrite the previous one
2. is a funny name like _OT3HJ~ (and not a date with time as I would have expected...)

Can someone help me a little?
Thanks and best regards,
Yannick

```
<?php 

$url = 'http://192.168.1.232:80/capture';

$img = '.new date("dmYHis").capture.jpg';

file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate PHP function output to a string like variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494038/concatenate-php-function-output-to-a-string-like-variables)

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not allow you to execute functions inside of string definitions like that. Luckily there are are numerous ways to solve this problem.

Simply concatenate the date result and the rest of the file name

```php
$img = date('dmYHis').'capture.jpg';
```

Use [complex syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) to insert the date variable in to the file name string

```php
$date = date('dmYHis');
$img2 = "{$date}capture.jpg";
```

Use [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to build the string

```php
$img3 = sprintf('%dcapture.jpg', date('dmYHis'));
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rob. I used the 1rst one and it works perfectly!